# A question about one-sided derivative

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ is continues in $x_0$ and suppose that $f'(x)$ exist around $x_0$, not nessesarly in $x_0$. Consider the limits 
$$
L=\lim_{x\to x_0^{-}}f'(x)\qquad R=\lim_{x\to x_0^{+}}f'(x)
$$
I know that if $L$, $R$ exist, finite and equal, then $f'(x_0)$ exist and equal to $L$ (or $R$). In addition, I know that it possible that $f'(x_0)$ exist, although  $L$ and $R$ does not exist, e.g. if 
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2\sin(1/x) & x\neq0\\
0& x=0
\end{cases}
$$

Is it possible that $L=R=\infty$ but $f'(x_0)$ still exist? or that $L$ finite and exist, $R$ does not exist but $f'(x_0)$ still exist? What can be said if $L=\infty$ and $R=-\infty$ etc. ? 
Thanks!

Comment: You know wrong, then. Consider $f(x)=|x|$ and $x_0=0$. Then $L=-1$, $R=1$, and $f'(0)$ is still not defined.

Comment: You right, Thanks @Asaf Karagila. I had a mistake. I meant $L=R$. I fixed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By mean value theorem and definition of derivative we can easily show that if $L$ exists finitely/infinitely then the left derivative also exists finitely/infinitely and is equal to $L$ and same remark applies to $R$. If $L, R$ exist then the existence of derivative is solely dependent on equality $L=R$.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Perhaps there is some confusion as the downvote is reversed. Let me know if some clarification is needed.

Comment: Thanks  @Paramanand Singh. So if $L=\pm\infty$ or $R=\pm\infty$, then $f'(x_0)$ does not exist?

Comment: @boaz: If $L=R=\pm\infty$ then we have a case where the tangent is parallel to y-axis and we can say that the derivative is infinite. But I prefer to call this case as non-existence of the derivative. But if $L\neq R$ irrespective of the values of $L, R$ being finite or infinite there is no tangent at the concerned point and derivative does not exist. You can check for example the case $f(x) =x^{1/3}$ at $x=0$ for infinite derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f'$ satisfy intermediate value property,

Therefore answers are (resp) 1- NO  2-yes   3-Yes

As an example for case 2 consider $$  f(x)=
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2\sin(1/x) & x > 0\\
0& x \leq 0
\end{cases}$$

example for 3.  $f(x)= - \sqrt{|x|}$